# Changing activity and persist

Tags: java, android, android-activity, persistence

can you help me to understand what is the different between change the activity and rotate the screan?

I can persist the data when i rotate the screan but when i change to other activity and return the data is not persisting

can you help me?

Comment: How are you persisting the info? What is happening exactly?

Comment: i am persisting with two void , this work only for rotate

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle estado) {
        // Save the user's current game state
        string = String.valueOf(textoexportar.getText());

        estado.putString("cuenta",string);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(estado);

        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    }

    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle estado){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(estado);

        string = estado.getString("cuenta");
        textoexportar.setText(string);



    }

Comment: i have a button to go to other activity and when i return at the first the info that i save into the string is missing =(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Comment: That a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state but basically the instance state is not the right way of persisting info. If you want to store the information through multiples uses take a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Thx denis for the quick answer, i am a little bit lost, i only want persist one variable string what do you recomend me?? , and why this way is working with the rotate and no with the change of activities??? many thx !!!

Comment: denis what do you thing if i create a class and i store with propertys in there?

Comment: Another class still wouldnt persist. I would recommend using the SharedPreferences. I wrote an answear for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220436/entering-app-exactly-as-it-was-left/45222321#45222321